# Angular JS + AlaSQL import

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, alasql

I am working on a project where I had to import Excel data and create a web view for it, my current solution now is to parse it on C# and send the JSON result as API, I just discovered AlaSQL, importing the data with pure JS worked fine, but I can't figure out how to load it from controller to replace my current $http.get(..)

In short I need to replace Http.get with a call to  an xls file on sitting on SharePoint using alasql and access data directly from the array.

Edit: Another way i will try to go is create a factory out of the returned java object from the excel file
Current code:

```
$http.get("xxx/file.json")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.xdata = response.data;
        $scope.zdata = response.data;
        $scope.collection = response.data;

        $scope.labels = [];
        $scope.data = [];

        $scope.datalength = $scope.zdata.length;

        $scope.loading = True;
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you want onload the controller event?

Comment: Exactly, its the same data that I import with http.get onload

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have mentioned basic controller samples. Please use it.

```
app.controller('DataViewCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    //scope variable declaration 

    //local function
    function loadDefaultValues(){
        $scope.loading = true;
        $http.get("xxx/file.json")
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.xdata = response.data;
            $scope.zdata = response.data;
            $scope.collection = response.data;

            $scope.labels = [];
            $scope.data = [];

            $scope.datalength = $scope.zdata.length;

            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    }

    //scope function

    //call onload functions
    loadDefaultValues();
   }
});
```

Comment: I don;t get how will this solve the problem in question, which is to load the Data from Excel instead of JSON using AlaSQL

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to run :

```
alasql(['SELECT * FROM FILE("file.xls",{headers:true})']).then(function(data){ 

        console.log(data[0]);
            $scope.xdata = JSON.stringify(data[0]);
            $scope.zdata = JSON.stringify(data[0]);
            $scope.collection = JSON.stringify(data[0]);

            $scope.labels = [];
            $scope.data = [];

            $scope.datalength = $scope.zdata.length;

            $scope.loading = true;
        });
}
```

However rendering it with NG-repeat is unbelievably slow